# When to use append() and when the += operator in Python?

Tags: list, dictionary, append, operators

This is my first question on Stack Overflow.

I want to add a new dictionary at the end of an existing list with multiple dictionaries (see example below):

```
travel_log = [
  {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 12,
    "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]
  },
  {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 5,
    "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]
  },
]

new_country = {
    "country": country,
    "visits": int(visits),
    "cities": list_of_cities,
  }
```

`new_country` needs to be added to the list of `travel_log`, but for a certain reason if I write:

`travel_log += new_country`

It does not work, while

`travel_log.append(new_country)`

will give the correct result.

I thought until now that the `+=` operator could be used in lists quite easily, but I am now a bit confused. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can use `travel_log += [new_country]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+=` operator is used to extend a list with the elements of another iterable. However, when you want to add a single element to a list (not an iterable), you should use the append method.

so if you use `+=` with 2 list it will concatenate them.

`+=`: Extends the list with the elements of another iterable.
`append()`: Adds a single element to the end of the list.

That is why `append` is working.

example:

```
   travel_log = [ { "country": "France", "visits": 12, "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"] }, { "country": "Germany", "visits": 5, "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"] }, ]
    
   new_country = [{ "country": country, "visits": int(visits), "cities": list_of_cities, }]

   travel_log+=new_country
```

This should work using `+=`
and if you want to use exact with append it will be:

```
travel_log.append(new_country[0])
```

otherwise you will have a list appended instead of a dict